# How to print the dataframe name (in a for loop)?

Tags: r

So, I am wanting to check the age range of each dataframe selected.

I can do this using the lapply method but I don't seem to find a solution for a simpler task:

"To get the dataframe name (e.g. ddf, nc_df, ad_df, etc...check below)"

Any help?

Here is my code:

```
dfList <- list(ddf,nc_df, ad_df, pd_df, ftd_df,mci_df,scc_df)

lapply(dfList, function(x){ print(<HERE IS THE CODE I NEED>) ; summary(x$Age) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just name your variables when you make the list. Here's a reproducible example:

```
a <- data.frame(1:5, Age = 6:10)
b <- data.frame(1:5, Age = 6:10)
c <- data.frame(1:5, 6:10, Age = 11:15)
dfList <- list(a = a, b = b, c = c)

lapply(dfList, function(x){ summary(x$Age) })
```

Alternatively, you can just name after the fact with

```
names(dfList) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```